# how check all columns in sql with certain value

Tags: mysql, dynamic, wildcard

i do have a MySQL table with 54 columns in it. Those 54 sql columns, has a possible Integer value of 3, 2, 1 or 0. How can i search all the columns with a value of 3 without naming the column name?, just something like a wildcard representation, since i can't name all 54 columns. I wanted to know if there is something like it in MySQL?

Here's an example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE * = 3 ; -- i know this is a wrong mysql syntax, but this is what i'm trying to achieved.
```

Comment: That can't be done and smells like bad table design. If you show your sructure we might be able to help you design a better one

Comment: @jurgen hi, thanks for the reply! i only wanted to extract at least   4 ids, with column value of 3...

my table is something like:
| id | employee_id | column_1 | column_2 | column_3 | and so on... until 54 columns overall.

Comment: please visit the following: http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/the-ten-most-asked-sql-server-questions--1/#2  solution in the blog post